# What is the easiest/lightest setup to get a basic LAMP stack setup for development?

Tags: development, lamp, http-server

I'm looking for a minimum of fuss here to get up and running.

Bonuses: 
 - cross platform
 - portable (can be installed/run from a USB)

*Clarification: I'm not looking to setup a full-fledged remote testing server, I just need something simple that I can load localhost in my computer's browser and check my latest changes.*

Comment: This belongs on ServerFault.

Comment: I disagree RandomBen, I believe it *was* the place to put it but with this new site, questions like this now also have a place here.

Comment: it is vaguely on topic, since as a webmaster you might want some local stuff set up.

Comment: @RandomBen What? I have set up dozens of local dev for different projects, languages, platforms yet have never had to build a server rack for development purposes. Isn't running a local dev environment considered a 'best practice' for web devs? How could this be considered 'off topic' when it's a fundamental workflow to web developers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html).  It is also easy to do with [PortableApps.com](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/xampp) but you don't need PortableApps to do it on a removable drive.

Answer (score 5):

Some options include:

- [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html): (Cross Platform) Comes with Apache, MySQL, PHP and Perl support out of the box and is portable but needs manual configuration if you defer from the default.
- [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/): (Windows) Comes with Apache, MySQL and PHP support out of the box and allows simple configuration through the tray icon. This also installs as a service so it's not portable.
- [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html): (Mac) Comes with Apache, MySQL and PHP support out of the box.
- [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/): (Windows) Comes with Apache, MySQL and PHP support out of the box and is portable.

Answer (score 0):

[Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) is easy to install and you can choose to install it in portable form on a USB drive.